# How can I count runs in a sequence?

Tags: r, count

In R, what would be the most efficient/simplest way to count runs of identical elements in a sequence?

For example, how to count the numbers of consecutive zeros in a sequence of non-negative integers:

```
x <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0) # should give 3,5,2
```

Comment: Do you want answers in R?

If so, it's probably wise to start the question with "In R ..." rather than just having an R tag.

Comment: Note: this doesn't work with runs of NAs or NaNs (they always get treated as non-contiguous). An ugly hack workaround would be to assign NAs and NaNs to some sentinel integer values.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use `rle()`:

```
y <- rle(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0))
y$lengths[y$values==0]
```

Comment: And how would you plot a histogram from this data?
Imagine I have numbers from 1 to 100, and squences of different lengths.  And I want to create the histogram showing how often runs of some length happens happen or numbers happen or both things.

Comment: This is not the place for a new question.

Answer (score 28):

This can be done in an efficient way by using indexes of where the values change:

```
x <- c(1,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,1,1)
```

Find where the values change:

```
diffs <- x[-1L] != x[-length(x)]
```

Get the indexes, and then get the difference in subsequent indexes:

```
idx <- c(which(diffs), length(x))
diff(c(0, idx))
```

Comment: That's essentially what rle() is doing.

Comment: Sorry Rob. Wrote that on my iPhone earlier, and there's no "app for that". :). Please vote for Rob's answer instead of mine!

Comment: +1: While `rle()` is an easier way to answer the OP's question, this solution has other advantages for some cases. In particular, I was looking for a way to number each run uniquely rather than counting the runs and I found I could do that with `c(0,cumsum(x[-1L] != x[-length(x)]))`.

Comment: Thank you Shane, very helpful :)