# Maximum of a consecutive sequence in a column with zeros

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe

```
id = 1:16
vals = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
cumsum  = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
test = data.frame(id,vals, cumsum)
```

I would like to extract the maximum of test$cumsum for each consecutive sequence.
For instance,
I can slice the column cumsum of test such that i have the consecutive sequences :

```
S1 = {0}
S2 = {1,2,3}
S3 = {0,0,0,0}
S4 = {1,2,3}
S5 = {0,0,0}
S6 = {1} 
S7 = {0}
```

As you can see, the zeros slice out my column into different sequences.
What i want to return, is the maximum of each non-zero sequence.
So I would get

```
returned_vector <- c(3,3,1)
```

Where the first entry of the returned_vector is the maximum of S2 (the first non-zero sequence), the second entry of the returned_vector is the maximum of S4 (the second non-zero sequence), the third entry of of the returned_vector is the maximum of S6 (the final non-zero sequence)

I am not sure how I can do it. Basically I just want to return the maximum of all non-zero sequences in my column test$cumsum.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `rle` could work: `r = rle(vals)`; `r$lengths[r$values == 1]`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is answered here: [How do I calculate the length of consecutive runs of events, e.g. wins, visits, in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968575/how-do-i-calculate-the-length-of-consecutive-runs-of-events-e-g-wins-visits); [How can I count runs in a sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502910/how-can-i-count-runs-in-a-sequence)

Comment: Thanks Henrik! This also works!!

Comment: @Lola1993: Please don't accept my answer. Its just *one* way to do it, and as you can see in Henrik's comment, there are much shorter, faster base R solutions.

Comment: @Henrik. This is fantastic to know. I really had a hard time to get it to work with `dplyr`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```r
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  group_by(id = data.table::rleid(vals)) %>% 
  summarise(max = ifelse(sum(vals) != 0,
                         list(max(cumsum, na.rm = TRUE)),
                         list(NULL))
            ) %>% 
  pull(max) %>%
  unlist

#> [1] 3 3 1

# the data
id = 1:16
vals = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
cumsum  = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
test = data.frame(id,vals, cumsum)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

1. Create unique `group_id` depending on `vals`
2. add a column `my.sequence` with sequences within `group_id`
3. `filter` and `summarise`
4. then get the vector `my_result`

```
library(dplyr)

test <- test %>% 
    mutate(
        group_id = cumsum(vals != lag(vals, def = first(vals)))
    ) %>% 
    group_by(group_id) %>% 
    mutate(my.sequence = row_number()) %>% 
    filter(vals ==1) %>% 
    summarise(result = max(my.sequence)) 

my_result <- test$result
my_result
```

Output:

```
[1] 3 3 1
```