# Replacing row values with the closest conditional values in R

Tags: r, replace

In R, I have a problem that is similar to the one presented here: [Replacing NAs in R with nearest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077415/replacing-nas-in-r-with-nearest-value). The differences however, are that the values that I want to change are not NAs but any value less than 0, and also that changing these values is dependent on values in another column (so a conditional statement would need to be added). I'm having trouble understanding how to adapt some of the solutions presented in that question to my problem. It's also important that this be speedy as I have a lot of data.

sample data

```
pred_trip <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
locNumb <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,2,2,2,3,3,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5)
df <- data.frame(pred_trip, locNumb)
```

So essentially if a value in the locNumb column is <= 0 and there is a 0 in the pred_trip column then the value in the locNumb column gets reassigned to the closest value that is greater than 0.

Desired output:

```
   pred_trip locNumb
1          0       2
2          0       2
3          0       2
4          0       2
5          0       2
6          1       2
7          1       2
8          1       2
9          1       2
10         0       3
11         0       3
12         0       3
13         1       0
14         1       0
15         1       4
16         0       4
17         0       4
18         0       4
19         0       4
20         0       4
21         0       4
22         0       4
23         0       4
24         0       4
25         0       4
26         0       4
27         1       0
28         1       0
29         1       0
30         1       5
31         1       5
32         1       5
33         1       5
```

I'm having trouble adapting the code in the similar solution as it relies a lot on is.na and doesn't include any of the other conditions that I need. But so in pseudo code something like: (not sure where to add in my other conditional statement of if pred_trip == 0.

```
f1 <- function(df) {
  N <- length(df)
  na.pos <- which(df$locNumb < 0 (df))
  if (length(na.pos) %in% c(0, N)) {
    return(df)
  }
  non.na.pos <- which(!df$locNumb < 0(df))
  intervals  <- findInterval(na.pos, non.na.pos,
                             all.inside = TRUE)
  left.pos   <- non.na.pos[pmax(1, intervals)]
  right.pos  <- non.na.pos[pmin(N, intervals+1)]
  left.dist  <- na.pos - left.pos
  right.dist <- right.pos - na.pos

  df[na.pos] <- ifelse(left.dist <= right.dist,
                    df[left.pos], df[right.pos])
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: What's desired output if there are 2 nearest values (before the negative number and after the negative numbers) that are greater than 0?

Comment: @geektrader, in that case the values before the negative numbers (numbers <= 0) should take precedence.

Comment: What should happen if `locNumb` is <0, & `pre_trip` does not =0? I don't see any such cases in your example data. Are there none in your real application? If not, this becomes simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

`rle` will give you run length encodings, from which you can replace the negative values with `NA` and then using `na.locf` function from `zoo` package to carry forward (and carry backward) the nearest non negative values. Finally, `inverse.rle` function can create your desired vector back which we can add to our original data.frame `df` as `newlocNumb`

As for any additional condition can be used to replace back some of the original values in `locNumb` column into `newlocNumb` column

```
require(zoo)
pred_trip <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
locNumb <- c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5)
df <- data.frame(pred_trip, locNumb)

RLE <- rle(df$locNumb)

RLE
## Run Length Encoding
##   lengths: int [1:8] 5 4 2 3 4 5 6 4
##   values : num [1:8] -1 2 3 0 4 -1 0 5


RLE$values[RLE$values < 0] <- NA

while (any(is.na(RLE$values))) {
    RLE$values <- na.locf(na.locf(RLE$values, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
}

df$newlocNumb <- inverse.rle(RLE)

df
##    pred_trip locNumb newlocNumb
## 1          0      -1          2
## 2          0      -1          2
## 3          0      -1          2
## 4          0      -1          2
## 5          0      -1          2
## 6          1       2          2
## 7          1       2          2
## 8          1       2          2
## 9          1       2          2
## 10         0       3          3
## 11         0       3          3
## 12         0       0          0
## 13         1       0          0
## 14         1       0          0
## 15         1       4          4
## 16         0       4          4
## 17         0       4          4
## 18         0       4          4
## 19         0      -1          4
## 20         0      -1          4
## 21         0      -1          4
## 22         0      -1          4
## 23         0      -1          4
## 24         0       0          0
## 25         0       0          0
## 26         0       0          0
## 27         1       0          0
## 28         1       0          0
## 29         1       0          0
## 30         1       5          5
## 31         1       5          5
## 32         1       5          5
## 33         1       5          5
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` library, which is also very efficient with memory usage btw, can be used here -

```
library(data.table)

# converting data.frame to data.table
dt <- data.table(df)

#assigning unique id to each row
dt[,grpno := .I]

# getting all the unique values from the data.table where locNumb > 0
positivelocNumb <- unique(dt[locNumb > 0])

# indexing by grpno, this will be used to help define nearest positive locnumb
setkeyv(positivelocNumb,c('grpno'))
setkeyv(dt,c('grpno'))

# nearest positive value join
dt2 <- positivelocNumb[dt, roll = "nearest"]
```

Output, where `pred_trip.1` and `locNumb.1` are the original values and `pred_trip` and `locNumb` are the closest positive values. You can exclude the  `pred_trip` column from being in the merge by creating `positivelocNumb` as `unique(dt[locNumb > 0,list(locNumb,grpno)])`  -

```
> dt2
    grpno pred_trip locNumb pred_trip.1 locNumb.1
 1:     1         1       2           0        -1
 2:     2         1       2           0        -1
 3:     3         1       2           0        -1
 4:     4         1       2           0        -1
 5:     5         1       2           0        -1
 6:     6         1       2           1         2
 7:     7         1       2           1         2
 8:     8         1       2           1         2
 9:     9         1       2           1         2
10:    10         0       3           0         3
11:    11         0       3           0         3
12:    12         0       3           0         0
13:    13         0       3           1         0
14:    14         1       4           1         0
15:    15         1       4           1         4
16:    16         0       4           0         4
17:    17         0       4           0         4
18:    18         0       4           0         4
19:    19         0       4           0        -1
20:    20         0       4           0        -1
21:    21         0       4           0        -1
22:    22         0       4           0        -1
23:    23         0       4           0        -1
24:    24         0       4           0         0
25:    25         1       5           0         0
26:    26         1       5           0         0
27:    27         1       5           1         0
28:    28         1       5           1         0
29:    29         1       5           1         0
30:    30         1       5           1         5
31:    31         1       5           1         5
32:    32         1       5           1         5
33:    33         1       5           1         5
```