# How to speed up the simulation when processing time and date

Tags: r

I am trying to program a forecasting method in R. The predictors are weather variables in addition to lag measured Power values. The accuracy of data is one minute and their corresponding time and date are available.
To add lag values of power to the predictors list, I am aiming to consider last ten minutes values. If I was sure that the database is perfect and the values for all minutes throughout the year are available I could simply shift the Power columns but as it may not be always the case, I have used the following codes for each time t to check if all its corresponding ten minutes lag values are available and extract them and store in a matrix. The problem is that, the process is highly time consuming and it takes a long time to be simulated. Here I ve given reproducible example. 
I have tried to change as.POSIXlt to as.POSIXct the simulation time gets better but not that much. I ve also tried to change the data.frame to matrix (using as. matrix)but it convert the POSIXct values to "character" class.
I was wondering any of you can suggest a better approach. Thank you.

```
rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")

st="2012/01/01"
et="2012/02/27"

st <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(st))
et <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(et))
time= seq(from=st, to=et,by=60)
time<as.POSIXlt(time)
#Window is the number of lag values
#leadTime is look-ahead time (forecast horizon)
leadTime=10;
Window=15;

zzzz=time[1:8000]
Total_Zone1=abind(matrix(rnorm(4000*2),4000*2,1), matrix(rnorm(4000*2),4000*2,1), matrix(rnorm(4000*2),4000*2,1),time[1:8000])
N_Train=nrow(Total_Zone1);
lag_Power=matrix(0,N_Train,Window)
colnames(Total_Zone1) <- c( "airtemp","humidity",  "Power", "time")
Total_Zone1<- as.data.frame(Total_Zone1)
for (tt in 4000:N_Train){
  Statlag=Total_Zone1$time[tt]-(leadTime+Window)*60
  EndLag=Total_Zone1$time[tt]-(leadTime)*60
  Index_lags=which((Total_Zone1$time>Statlag)&(Total_Zone1$time<=EndLag))
  if (size(Index_lags)[2]<Window) {
    Statlag2=Total_Zone1$time[tt]-24*60*60
    Index_lags2=which(Total_Zone1$time==Statlag2)
    tem1=rep(Total_Zone1[Index_lags2,c("Power")],Window-size(Index_lags)[2])
    lag_Power[tt,]=t(c(Total_Zone1[Index_lags,c("Power")],tem1))
  }else{
     lag_Power[tt,]=t(Total_Zone1[Index_lags,c("Power")])
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the `size()` function? I've never seen that before, and don't seem to have it in my R (`Error: could not find function "size"`).

Comment: It's similar to size() in Matlab and works like "dim" in R. I can't remember the  package which it belongs to. better to use "dim" or "length" to be safe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `rolling merge` from the `data.table` package should work well here:

```
#Bring in data.table package
library(data.table)
setDT(Total_Zone1) #Convert data to data.table
leadTime=10
Window=15
Total_Zone1[, time2 := time-60*(leadTime)]

#Create lag table
Lag_Table <- Total_Zone1[,.(time,Lag.Power=Power)]

#Set keys and perform rolling merge
setkey(Total_Zone1,time2)
setkey(Lag_Table,time)

#Perform rolling merge in data.table
Result <- Lag_Table[Total_Zone1,roll=+(Window*60)]
```

And the results:

```
Result[1:15]

          time   Lag.Power    airtemp   humidity       Power     i.time
 1: 1325375400          NA  0.5341823  0.6114278  0.01378526 1325376000
 2: 1325375460          NA -0.4063909  1.0928144 -0.63712941 1325376060
 3: 1325375520          NA -1.3841581 -0.6204582  0.80553870 1325376120
 4: 1325375580          NA  1.5146208 -0.4343324 -1.29370219 1325376180
 5: 1325375640          NA -1.4949108  0.1416236 -0.64836292 1325376240
 6: 1325375700          NA -1.7832364 -1.2018948 -1.13257989 1325376300
 7: 1325375760          NA -1.2111490  0.5819049  0.22450291 1325376360
 8: 1325375820          NA -0.2837945  0.3196630  0.43199908 1325376420
 9: 1325375880          NA -1.2773624  0.3724754 -1.31807585 1325376480
10: 1325375940          NA  0.7710507 -1.0114118 -0.85951358 1325376540
11: 1325376000  0.01378526  0.7983597  1.7683065  0.38032568 1325376600
12: 1325376060 -0.63712941  0.3813563 -0.3905894  1.47871752 1325376660
13: 1325376120  0.80553870  0.7421624 -1.2265799  0.34509387 1325376720
14: 1325376180 -1.29370219  0.7768929 -1.2244243 -0.02769379 1325376780
15: 1325376240 -0.64836292 -0.8311352  0.8486815  0.16926006 1325376840
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. Your comment was quite helpful. Basically I need to use a window of lag data. for example to predict power for 8 am I need to use data from 7:35 am to 7:50 am (lead time=10 minutes, and Window=15 minutes, with minute resolution). How can i manage to perform it without using a for loop. Many thanks.

Comment: Ah..i think i get it. I changed it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would suggest would be to separate the task of *filling in missing data* from that of *reformatting your data*. You've combined those two tasks in your `for` loop, but I think the code can be simplified and accelerated by doing this separation.

To demonstrate, I'll use my own simplified example code and data, which is similar to yours. The following demo uses an hour's worth of time points, from 2012-01-01 09:00 to 2012-01-01 09:59. I've generated complete data for the first 20min, and simulated missing data for the remaining 40min:

```
timeFirst20Min <- seq(as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 09:00'),as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 09:19'),60);
timeNextScattered10 <- sort(sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 09:20'),as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 09:59'),60),10));
timeRaw <- c(timeFirst20Min,timeNextScattered10);

raw <- data.frame(airtemp=rnorm(30), humidity=rnorm(30), power=rnorm(30), time=timeRaw );

timeFull <- seq(as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 09:00'),as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 09:59'),60);

clean <- merge(raw, data.frame(time=timeFull), all=T );

clean;
```

This results in the following output:

```
                  time     airtemp    humidity       power
1  2012-01-01 09:00:00 -1.84406568 -1.51751811 -0.09391613
2  2012-01-01 09:01:00 -0.58830616 -0.02222524 -0.07865711
3  2012-01-01 09:02:00  1.63189916 -1.35274437 -1.32762005
4  2012-01-01 09:03:00 -1.96424678  0.07326323 -0.29004060
5  2012-01-01 09:04:00 -0.60856223  1.15876062  0.29804843
6  2012-01-01 09:05:00 -0.11504175 -0.43092259  0.49660688
7  2012-01-01 09:06:00  0.24671752  0.58974028 -1.08949827
8  2012-01-01 09:07:00  0.88375964  0.35821875 -0.94881659
9  2012-01-01 09:08:00 -0.70284907 -2.39016066  0.03804497
10 2012-01-01 09:09:00  1.34738493  0.64676077  0.77714355
11 2012-01-01 09:10:00  0.32271920  1.83127669 -1.44754595
12 2012-01-01 09:11:00 -0.46106830 -1.82204149  1.28886422
13 2012-01-01 09:12:00  2.27484699 -1.29816051  0.67963614
14 2012-01-01 09:13:00 -0.25799515 -0.23864259  0.33414247
15 2012-01-01 09:14:00  0.27535436  1.15491712  1.25857697
16 2012-01-01 09:15:00  0.09447671  0.72562227  0.35426141
17 2012-01-01 09:16:00  2.46141564  0.10448464 -0.04715810
18 2012-01-01 09:17:00  0.32952643 -0.51843045 -0.44380916
19 2012-01-01 09:18:00  0.34571678  1.74200137  2.05858658
20 2012-01-01 09:19:00  0.62863598 -0.38642998  1.29170691
21 2012-01-01 09:20:00          NA          NA          NA
22 2012-01-01 09:21:00          NA          NA          NA
23 2012-01-01 09:22:00  0.83148733 -0.79160256 -0.98798400
24 2012-01-01 09:23:00          NA          NA          NA
25 2012-01-01 09:24:00          NA          NA          NA
26 2012-01-01 09:25:00          NA          NA          NA
27 2012-01-01 09:26:00 -0.80548958  0.99318673  0.49630420
28 2012-01-01 09:27:00          NA          NA          NA
29 2012-01-01 09:28:00 -1.12821534 -0.64763280  0.28033445
30 2012-01-01 09:29:00          NA          NA          NA
31 2012-01-01 09:30:00  1.77407448  0.21064525  0.97942804
32 2012-01-01 09:31:00          NA          NA          NA
33 2012-01-01 09:32:00 -0.71832822  0.89608884 -0.14460970
34 2012-01-01 09:33:00          NA          NA          NA
35 2012-01-01 09:34:00          NA          NA          NA
36 2012-01-01 09:35:00          NA          NA          NA
37 2012-01-01 09:36:00          NA          NA          NA
38 2012-01-01 09:37:00          NA          NA          NA
39 2012-01-01 09:38:00          NA          NA          NA
40 2012-01-01 09:39:00 -0.17353680  1.69963228  0.10863195
41 2012-01-01 09:40:00  1.03484529  1.69734966  3.00898820
42 2012-01-01 09:41:00          NA          NA          NA
43 2012-01-01 09:42:00          NA          NA          NA
44 2012-01-01 09:43:00 -1.13983790  1.51982921  0.58583242
45 2012-01-01 09:44:00          NA          NA          NA
46 2012-01-01 09:45:00          NA          NA          NA
47 2012-01-01 09:46:00          NA          NA          NA
48 2012-01-01 09:47:00          NA          NA          NA
49 2012-01-01 09:48:00          NA          NA          NA
50 2012-01-01 09:49:00          NA          NA          NA
51 2012-01-01 09:50:00          NA          NA          NA
52 2012-01-01 09:51:00          NA          NA          NA
53 2012-01-01 09:52:00 -0.93153818  0.77736403  2.08962697
54 2012-01-01 09:53:00          NA          NA          NA
55 2012-01-01 09:54:00  2.26031675 -0.49847630 -1.48191078
56 2012-01-01 09:55:00          NA          NA          NA
57 2012-01-01 09:56:00          NA          NA          NA
58 2012-01-01 09:57:00          NA          NA          NA
59 2012-01-01 09:58:00          NA          NA          NA
60 2012-01-01 09:59:00          NA          NA          NA
```

So the first task would be to interpolate the missing power values on `clean`. Now, in your code, it appears that you're looking backwards a full 24hr period to grab the power value that existed at exactly that time prior to the base time point (if it exists; it's not guaranteed to exist, is it?), and replicating that onto the end of the vector representing the power measurements that were taken during the window period. This is the code I'm referring to:

```
Statlag2=Total_Zone1$time[tt]-24*60*60
Index_lags2=which(Total_Zone1$time==Statlag2)
tem1=rep(Total_Zone1[Index_lags2,c("Power")],Window-size(Index_lags)[2])
lag_Power[tt,]=t(c(Total_Zone1[Index_lags,c("Power")],tem1))
```

I'm not sure why you're looking backwards 24hr, especially considering the window is only 15min and ends only 10min prior to the base time point. I'm also not sure why you've added the interpolation value (replicated sufficiently to cover the shortfall in available power values) onto the *end* of the row that is stored on `lag_Power`; shouldn't it be the beginning, especially considering the interpolated value comes from such a long time prior to the window? I may be missing important context here; please comment if I'm missing something.

In any case, what I would do is fill in the missing power values from the nearest available values in time. I found an excellent nearest-interpolation function that can work directly on an individual vector from [Replacing NAs in R with nearest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077415/replacing-nas-in-r-with-nearest-value). Here it is, with my own reformatting:

```
interpolateMissing <- function(dat) {

    N <- length(dat);
    missing <- which(is.na(dat));
    if (length(missing) %in% c(0,N)) return(dat);

    notMissing <- which(!is.na(dat));
    intervals <- findInterval(missing, notMissing, all.inside=T );

    leftPos <- notMissing[pmax(1,intervals)];
    rightPos <- notMissing[pmin(N,intervals+1)];
    leftDist <- missing - leftPos;
    rightDist <- rightPos - missing;

    dat[missing] <- ifelse(leftDist <= rightDist, dat[leftPos], dat[rightPos] );

    return(dat);

};
```

You can use this to easily interpolate all missing power values from the nearest available value:

```
clean$power <- interpolateMissing(clean$power);
```

`clean` now looks like this:

```
                  time     airtemp    humidity       power
1  2012-01-01 09:00:00 -1.84406568 -1.51751811 -0.09391613
2  2012-01-01 09:01:00 -0.58830616 -0.02222524 -0.07865711
3  2012-01-01 09:02:00  1.63189916 -1.35274437 -1.32762005
4  2012-01-01 09:03:00 -1.96424678  0.07326323 -0.29004060
5  2012-01-01 09:04:00 -0.60856223  1.15876062  0.29804843
6  2012-01-01 09:05:00 -0.11504175 -0.43092259  0.49660688
7  2012-01-01 09:06:00  0.24671752  0.58974028 -1.08949827
8  2012-01-01 09:07:00  0.88375964  0.35821875 -0.94881659
9  2012-01-01 09:08:00 -0.70284907 -2.39016066  0.03804497
10 2012-01-01 09:09:00  1.34738493  0.64676077  0.77714355
11 2012-01-01 09:10:00  0.32271920  1.83127669 -1.44754595
12 2012-01-01 09:11:00 -0.46106830 -1.82204149  1.28886422
13 2012-01-01 09:12:00  2.27484699 -1.29816051  0.67963614
14 2012-01-01 09:13:00 -0.25799515 -0.23864259  0.33414247
15 2012-01-01 09:14:00  0.27535436  1.15491712  1.25857697
16 2012-01-01 09:15:00  0.09447671  0.72562227  0.35426141
17 2012-01-01 09:16:00  2.46141564  0.10448464 -0.04715810
18 2012-01-01 09:17:00  0.32952643 -0.51843045 -0.44380916
19 2012-01-01 09:18:00  0.34571678  1.74200137  2.05858658
20 2012-01-01 09:19:00  0.62863598 -0.38642998  1.29170691
21 2012-01-01 09:20:00          NA          NA  1.29170691
22 2012-01-01 09:21:00          NA          NA -0.98798400
23 2012-01-01 09:22:00  0.83148733 -0.79160256 -0.98798400
24 2012-01-01 09:23:00          NA          NA -0.98798400
25 2012-01-01 09:24:00          NA          NA -0.98798400
26 2012-01-01 09:25:00          NA          NA  0.49630420
27 2012-01-01 09:26:00 -0.80548958  0.99318673  0.49630420
28 2012-01-01 09:27:00          NA          NA  0.49630420
29 2012-01-01 09:28:00 -1.12821534 -0.64763280  0.28033445
30 2012-01-01 09:29:00          NA          NA  0.28033445
31 2012-01-01 09:30:00  1.77407448  0.21064525  0.97942804
32 2012-01-01 09:31:00          NA          NA  0.97942804
33 2012-01-01 09:32:00 -0.71832822  0.89608884 -0.14460970
34 2012-01-01 09:33:00          NA          NA -0.14460970
35 2012-01-01 09:34:00          NA          NA -0.14460970
36 2012-01-01 09:35:00          NA          NA -0.14460970
37 2012-01-01 09:36:00          NA          NA  0.10863195
38 2012-01-01 09:37:00          NA          NA  0.10863195
39 2012-01-01 09:38:00          NA          NA  0.10863195
40 2012-01-01 09:39:00 -0.17353680  1.69963228  0.10863195
41 2012-01-01 09:40:00  1.03484529  1.69734966  3.00898820
42 2012-01-01 09:41:00          NA          NA  3.00898820
43 2012-01-01 09:42:00          NA          NA  0.58583242
44 2012-01-01 09:43:00 -1.13983790  1.51982921  0.58583242
45 2012-01-01 09:44:00          NA          NA  0.58583242
46 2012-01-01 09:45:00          NA          NA  0.58583242
47 2012-01-01 09:46:00          NA          NA  0.58583242
48 2012-01-01 09:47:00          NA          NA  0.58583242
49 2012-01-01 09:48:00          NA          NA  2.08962697
50 2012-01-01 09:49:00          NA          NA  2.08962697
51 2012-01-01 09:50:00          NA          NA  2.08962697
52 2012-01-01 09:51:00          NA          NA  2.08962697
53 2012-01-01 09:52:00 -0.93153818  0.77736403  2.08962697
54 2012-01-01 09:53:00          NA          NA  2.08962697
55 2012-01-01 09:54:00  2.26031675 -0.49847630 -1.48191078
56 2012-01-01 09:55:00          NA          NA -1.48191078
57 2012-01-01 09:56:00          NA          NA -1.48191078
58 2012-01-01 09:57:00          NA          NA -1.48191078
59 2012-01-01 09:58:00          NA          NA -1.48191078
60 2012-01-01 09:59:00          NA          NA -1.48191078
```

So, now it is ready to use, without the need to worry about missing values.

One last point is, I'm not sure what the benefit is to constructing the `lag_Power` matrix. Each window overlaps considerably with other windows, so this matrix will contain significant duplication of data. Instead, I'd look at how that data is being used downstream from this preparatory code, and see if it can be changed to access the window-specific values directly in `clean` (or in your code, `Total_Zone1`). This could save both on processing time and on memory impact.

Comment: Thanks a million. My database contains measurements from 5 am to 7 pm. say if the forecasts lead time is 10 minutes and I plan to use "window=15" number of data as predictors. Therefore, for PV prediction for 5:25 am I will use  archived values for 5:00 am to 5:15. For performing prediction earlier than 5:25 am , because window number of lag data are not available, I decided to use the measured values of the day before day of concern and that thejob of the replication function in the for loop

Comment: One more thing is that, if measured values for some times are not available, in my database, they are not shown by Na values, in contrast their corresponding rows, including data and time and all the other values are not given. I mean for example in the database, data may jump from 9:12 am to 9:15 am (while the regular steps is one minute)

Comment: Yes, I understand, that makes a lot of sense. With respect to your second comment, my example code shows how to merge a full time sequence with raw data that is missing rows, as you describe. The `merge()` function (with `all=T`, importantly) basically adds those missing rows, with `NA` for the missing values, so I think that's perfect for your purposes. After the interpolation step, you end up with a nice clean table with no missing rows and no missing values. Hope it helps!