# Counting frequencies of Continuous Dates

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in the form:

```
Date
2011-08-16
2011-08-17
2011-08-28
2011-09-01
2011-09-05
2011-09-06
2011-10-01
2011-10-02
2011-10-03
2011-10-04
```

What I would like to do is take a run count when Dates occur in order i.e. they are side by side.

In the above example, we would have 2,1,1,2,4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

Make reproducible example data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "2011-08-16
2011-08-17
2011-08-28
2011-09-01
2011-09-05
2011-09-06
2011-10-01
2011-10-02
2011-10-03
2011-10-04")
```

Get the run count of consecutive dates using `rle`, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8401783/1036500) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503155/1036500):

```
(rle (cumsum( c(0, diff(as.Date(dat$V1)) > 1) ) ) )$lengths
[1] 2 1 1 2 4
```

Comment: Thank you.  Didn't know about diff!  You don't need cumsum for this though.

Comment: @davewolfs I'm not sure what you mean about not needing `cumsum`. If I leave it out like so: `(rle (( c(0, diff(as.Date(dat$V1)) > 1) ) ) )$lengths` then I get something different to what you want: `[1] 2 3 1 1 3`

Comment: `runs <- rle(c(1,diff(as.Date(dat$Date)) > 1))
table(runs$lengths[runs$values == 0])`