# How to get run of numbers in a vector using R

Tags: r

Let us consider a vector `x`,  where

```
 x=c(1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7).
```

I want to get the run vector (`y`) obtained from the above vector, that is,

```
y= 1 4 2 1 3 1 3.
```

I think there may be a function in R to do this task but I don't that function. Could anyone please suggest me what function do this task in R. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rle(x)$lengths` is what you are looking for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502910/how-can-i-count-runs-in-a-sequence

Comment: Thanks to all for the answer....I was guessing there may be answer in stackoverflow...but could not found it. Anyway thanks, I got the answer.